# Change code to process NumPy array instead of Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I need to change my code to work with `NumPy` 2D array instead of `pandas` dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[nan, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"])

list_of_NA_features = ["col1"]

for feature in list_of_NA_features:
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        if (pd.isnull(row[feature]) == True):
            missing_value = 5 # for simplicity, let's put 5 instead of a function
            df.ix[index,feature] = missing_val
```

What is the right way to do `for index,row in df.iterrows():`, `pd.isnull(row[feature]) == True` and `df.ix[index,feature] = missing_val` for `NumPy` array?

This is what I have done so far:

```
np_arr = df.as_matrix

for feature in list_of_NA_features:
    for feature in xrange(np_arr.shape[1]):
        # ???
```

How can I get the index of row to be able to perform `np_arr[irow,feature]`? Also what is the right way to assign values to particular row and column in `NumPy` arrays: `df.ix[index,feature] = missing_val`?

**UPDATE**

I simplified the code by deleting the function `fill_missing_values` and substituting it with the value `5`. However, in my real case I need to estimate the missing value.

Comment: i think the right way would be to use vectorized approach. But it's difficult without being able to see a small reproducible sample data set and a desired data set... ;-)

Comment: I suggest adding a simple example dataframe.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: It's just a function that returns an integer. Indeed it doesn't really matter in this case. Therefore I have not explained this function.

Comment: @MaxU Ok, one moment.

Comment: It should be easy. What is fill_missing_values? You need something like `subarr = arr[:,[c1,c2,c3]]; subarr[np.isnan(subarr)] = replacement_value`; more complicated if the replacement depends on index. Hopefully that works with a view and thus mutates the original array. Otherwise indexing is uglier.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: The replacement depends on a complex logic and index. Therefore, I guess it's hardly possible to vectorize the code.

Comment: I am guessing that's a too simplistic example. For an actual vectorized implementation, the exact use case would be needed.

Comment: @Divakar: Is it possible to avoid vectorized implementation? I only need to be able to iterate over numpy array and access row id and particular column by its name at each iteration.

Comment: Your updated version is too simple... it's not complete in terms of a [mcve]. You can always just loop over indices... but that's ugly in numpy. You can hide this by calling `np.vectorize` on your missing value function... but I ultimately suspect an XY problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Setup**

```
#setup a numpy array the same as your Dataframe
a = np.array([[np.nan,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.],
       [  7.,   8.,   9.]])

#list_of_NA_features now contains the column index in the numpy array
list_of_NA_features = [0]
```

**Solution:**

```
#Now you can see how those operations can be carried out on a numpy array. I'm just saying you can do this on a numpy array in the way you did it on a Dataframe. I'm not saying this is the best way of doing what you are trying to do.
for feature in list_of_NA_features:
    for index, row in enumerate(a):
        if np.isnan(row[feature]):
            missing_value = 5
            a[index,feature] = missing_value 

Out[167]: 
array([[ 5.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for.